# Тема дипломной работы

Tags: c#, delphi, java, c, c++

Здравствуйте. Так уж вышло, что учеба когда-нибудь да заканчивается, и пора задуматься о дипломе. Учусь на программиста. Дипломинатор давал темы, но они все скудные или непонятные. Хочу сделать что-то сложное, но реальное, что действительно тянет на курсач.
Пока на примете: распознователь текста (ImgToText).

Как вы считаете, хороша ли тема диплома?
(И если можно, то хотелось бы услышать и ваши предложения по поводу темы.)

Comment: @Manitikyl, вопросы опросники недопустимы в сообществе. Пожалуйста, перефразируйте вопрос таким образом, чтобы на него мог быть дан однозначный ответ.

Comment: Самый важный параметр диплома это "практическая выгода", на втором месте "экономическое обоснование", а на третьем "показать свои знания".

Answer (score 3):

Ну, насчет распознавателей текста от преподавателей будет один логичный вопрос - в чем новизна? И ответа на этот вопрос у Вас не будет. А по сабжу - не стоит искать сложных решений, когда есть простые. Тема диплома в будущем никому не будет интересна, как максимум, будет интересно его наличие. Поэтому либо берите одну из предложенных, либо предложите свою, которую идеально знаете и по которой есть наработки.

Comment: Как главное оружие, плюшку, я думал сделать - систему можно будет "обучать", что в дальнейшем приведет к распознованию и написанного вами текста, что нету например в FineReader. + можно сделать мобильное приложение :)

То что предложил дипломинатор, там забей) скучно и скудно явно не для диплома) я считаю что диплом это серьезная тема а не "смоделируй шурупчик и чтоб он крутился"

Comment: > Тема диплома в будущем никому не будет интересна

Если только ТС однажды не захочет снова попасть в стены академии.

Comment: @Manitikyl, в FineReader есть обучение распознаванию, по крайней мере раньше была, сам пользовался.

Answer (score 2):

Язык программирования, оформленный как заголовочный файл для C. То есть подключаем такой файл, пишем функции на С, после чего может компоновать их в функциональном стиле. За основу можно взять язык TRAC, например. Сделать более красивый синтаксис - с разными типами скобок вместо диезов и с отступами, как в Пайтоне. Ищите в англоязычной Википедии, а также в книге Чарльза Уэзерелла. "Этюды для программистов". Вот что я имею в виду, если более определенно:

```
void add(Trac trac)
{
    double a = Trac_GetDouble(trac);
    double b = Trac_GetDouble(trac);
    Trac_PutDouble(a + b);
}

Trac_RegisterFunction(trac, add, "add");

void mul(Trac trac)
{
    double a = Trac_GetDouble(trac);
    double b = Trac_GetDouble(trac);
    Trac_PutDouble(a * b);
}

Trac_RegisterFunction(trac, mul, "mul");

Trac_Eval("{add 1.0 {mul 3.0 4.0}}");
printf("lf\n", Trac_GetDouble(trac));
```

Выведется 13.00000

Разумеется, я не настаиваю на этом Траке, хотя язык неплохой. Отдаленно напоминает Лисп. Да, существует множество диалектов Лиспа и Схемы, в том числе встраиваемых в С, компилирующихся в С-код, легко вызывающихся из С-кода и т.д. Но вот такого "гладкого" сопряжения не видел.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя есть предложить что-то лучше FineReader? https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=распознать+текст&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Можно сделать автоматическое распознавание рекламных объявлений из скана газетного листа с сохранением названий компаний, телефонов и адресов. Или автоматический перевод сканов иностранных газет на нужный язык без интернета (без Google Translate).

Comment: главные минусы FineReader - платный, необучаемый, не читает рукописный текст, хочу давить на это (и если получится то на скорость)

Comment: По своему опыту знаю, что диплом пишется где-то в марте-апреле-мае. Давить, вероятнее всего, придется на скорость разработки, а не скорость программы.

Бесплатный продукт делать бессмысленно, он обречен на посредственное существование.
Обучать систему распознавания дело неблагодарное, она будет ВСЕГДА ошибаться.
Распознавать рукописный текст уже умеют другие программы.

Comment: @Manitikyl вы всерьез рассчитываете за несколько месяцев в одиночку реализовать то, чего нет в большом коммерческом продукте, который делает целая команда крутых профессионалов с многими годами опыта у каждого?

Comment: @Get я лично начну уже сейчас делать) ибо тема довольно-таки интересная. Монетизация, реклама, там баннерная, хороший доход.

@DreamChild прошу заметить что диплом это не обязательно конечный продукт, тут главное "ход ваших мыслей", алгоритм и ваш подход к данной проблеме, я думаю за несколько месяцев можно написать программу которая будет распозновать хотябы базовые случаи (если их можно так назвать), со словами: вот работает, а потенциал большой)

P.S. офк я не настаиваю на данной теме, хотел услышать от вас примеры :)

Comment: @Manitikyl, дело, конечно, ваше, но 90% студентов в IT расценивают диплом как отписку чтобы отстали. И они не так уж неправы, так как маразм в образовании крепчает с каждым годом

Comment: @z668 тогда вы должны хорошо понимать, что все эти институтские понты про новизну, актуальность и полезность дипломного проекта в большинстве случаев не более, чем пустословие. В противном случае 99% студентов никогда бы не написали и не защитили никаких дипломных проектов - написать что-то актуальное, новое и полезное зачастую не под силу даже опытным разработчикам (и даже целым командам), чего уж там требовать со студента-дипломника, который пока еще далеко не профессионал. Поэтому в большинстве случаев в качестве темы сойдет очень многое, поверьте

Comment: @z668 выбор, конечно, за ТСом, но выбирай я между Android и WinPhone, не раздумывая вsбрал бы первый (несмотря на то, что основная моя специализация - это C# + стек технологий Microsoft). Очень уж смутными видятся перспективы всего мобильного направления от Microsoft/ И если рассматривать диплом как получение полезного опыта, то полезность разработки под самую популярную мобильную платформу очевидна, а вот под WInPhone/WinRT ипрочее с туманным будущим - вовсе нет.

З.Ы. 

>координально изменилось

вы извините, конечно, не в обиду будет сказано, но это "координально" выглядит адски безграмонтн